# Where can I download a full international drug names dataset?

Tags: data-request, medical, drugs

Please advise where can I download a full international dataset of drug/medicine names?

I need a csv or db file with names

Comment: It looks like you have not done any research here? There are currently [42 questions about drug names](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+drug+names) on the site.

Comment: I did, none of them answer my question. I need a csv or db file with names. @JanDoggen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The World Health Organization maintains a list of International Nonproproprietary Names (INNs) for drugs in Latin, English, French and Spanish. You can download this list at https://www.who.int/medicines/publications/druginformation/innlists/RL82_pre.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Recently a dataset has been created that aims to collect such data for 44 countries:

- **Dataset:** Khaleel, Mohammad A.; Khan, Amer Hayat; Ghadzi, SM Sheikh; Alshakhshir, Sami (2021), “International Drug Dictionary (IDD)”, Mendeley Data, V1, doi: [10.17632/9nmgzttxhm.1](https://doi.org/10.17632/9nmgzttxhm.1)
- **Paper:** Khaleel, M. A., Khan, A. H., Ghadzi, S. S., & Alshakhshir, S. (2022). [Curation of an international drug proprietary names dataset](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.dib.2021.107701). Data in brief, 40, 107701.